# Webpage scrolls up when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I'm building a webpage with ASP.net where, when the button at the top of the page, it automatically scrolls down to a certain :

```
<script>
      function myFunction() {
         const element = document.getElementById("Results");
         element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
      }
</script>
```

But unfortunately, it goes back up again after the click.
I have tried a number of solutions, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var xPos, yPos;
 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
 prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
 prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
 function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
     xPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft;
     yPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop;
 }
 function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
     $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft = xPos;
     $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop = yPos;
}
</script>
```

or

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

but to no avail.

My button is coded as:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
        OnClientClick="myFunction()" Visible="true" Style="display: none" />
```

What other solutions should I try to implement?

Comment: What kind of button is there. Can you put your button html in your question. There could be may reasons like postback, javascript error etc.

Comment: do you see any error on console?

Comment: I only see warnings: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ihhkmalpkhkoedlmcnilbbhhbhnicjga/1110.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT @शेखर

Comment: Check updates for the Button html @शेखर

Comment: do you want to do some server side code also on the same button click? As there is a postback happing so it is reloading the page. What is the used case of server side code.

Comment: If you don't want postback modify the function put `return false;` at the end of the function an in call  `OnClientClick="return myFunction()"`. But it will stop button form doing postback.

Comment: change this point `OnClientClick="myFunction();return false;"` and try again to see if its works

Comment: @Aristos Unfortunately I am indeed in need to do backend code so I need postback

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira, then this is not the way - add an anchor and go there after the post back, or use UpdatePanel